# How can I make an Image move according to my mouse movement?(NOT FOLLOW THE MOUSE!!)

Tags: javascript, html

I need to move some images around as my mouse moves. For example, if the image is at (0,0) and the mouse is at (32,45) and moves to (32,47) then the image should move to (0,2) i.e. move the image to 2px y-direction

I tried the following but the images follow over like a trail.

```
var prevx = 0;
var prevy = 0; 
//move images with mouse
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    
        var image = images[i];
        var newx = event.pageX;
        var newy = event.pageY;
        var dx = newx - prevx;
        var dy = newy - prevy;
        //move image dx to left and dy to top
        image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left) + dx + "px";
        image.style.top = parseInt(image.style.top) + dy + "px";
        

        
    }
  }
);
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned I updated my code to the following

```
var prevx = 0;
var prevy = 0; 
//move images with mouse
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var newx = event.pageX;
      var newy = event.pageY;
      if (prevx!=0 && prevy!=0){
        var image = images[i];
        var dx = newx - prevx;
        var dy = newy - prevy;
        //move image dx to left nad dy to top
        image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left) + dx + "px";
        image.style.top = parseInt(image.style.top) + dy + "px";
      }
    }
        prevx = newx;
        prevy = newy;
  }
);
```

but the issue is somehow all the images anchor around the top left corner.

To give a clearer picture,

I have my webpage with multiple images at random positions and I need to move it whenever the mouse moves. I expect the photos to move according to how the mouse moves and not to follow the mouse pointer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I'm trying to understand what you want to do. So in the example, the image should only move by 2 pixels in the Y direction? What is your overall aim?

Comment: thanks !
yes I aim to move the image 2 pixels in y direction if the mouse moves 2 pixels in y direction. I have updated my query and perhaps you could get a clearer picture there!

Answer (score 1):

You forget to update prevX and Y, adding that we get something along the likes of:

```js
var prevx = 0;
var prevy = 0;
//move images with mouse
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

    var image = images[i];
    var newx = event.pageX;
    var newy = event.pageY;
    var dx = newx - prevx;
    var dy = newy - prevy;
    //move image dx to left nad dy to top
    image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left) + dx + "px";
    image.style.top = parseInt(image.style.top) + dy + "px";

    prevx = newx;
    prevy = newy;
  }
});
```

Note: this solution still has some "weird" behavior, at first, as prevx and prevy probably isn't 0 initially. Easy solution is just to only update position of img if prevx and prevy isn't 0.

Comment: thanks!
I did that somehow got left with another issue that some images gets fixed to top left corner.
I will update that in my question

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. I've also added how to keep the images contained in their parent element.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
let lastMouseX = null;
let lastMouseY = null;

// Start fresh if mouse leaves screen
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  lastMouseX = null;
  lastMouseY = null;
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (ev) => {
  // Do nothing if this is the first event
  if (lastMouseX !== null) {
    const deltaX = ev.x - lastMouseX;
    const deltaY = ev.y - lastMouseY;
    for (const img of images) {
      let newLeft = img.offsetLeft + deltaX;
      let newTop = img.offsetTop + deltaY;
      // Keep in bounds
      const minLeft = 0;
      const minTop = 0;
      const maxLeft = img.parentElement.clientWidth - img.clientWidth;
      const maxTop = img.parentElement.clientHeight - img.clientHeight;
      newLeft = Math.max(minLeft, newLeft);
      newLeft = Math.min(maxLeft, newLeft);
      newTop = Math.max(minTop, newTop);
      newTop = Math.min(maxTop, newTop);
      // update
      img.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
      img.style.top = newTop + 'px';
    }
  }
  lastMouseX = ev.x;
  lastMouseY = ev.y;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  padding: 20px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.one {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.two {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.three {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.four {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <img
    src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg"
  />
</div>
<div class="two">
  <img
    src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg"
  />
</div>
<div class="three">
  <img
    src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg"
  />
</div>
<div class="four">
  <img
    src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg"
  />
</div>
```

I've used `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` which is essentially the same as `style.left` and `style.top` but no need to parse it. You also need to make sure the images have a position of `absolute` or `fixed` for `style.left` and `style.top` to have an effect.